# How to change default color of a series chart in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series chart and in data , I have different colors for specific series range . I want to display different color series on the chart based on what I have in data . I try to update the code  but it is not working

in `var arraylist` some color is like  `color" : "#00FF00"` and some others `"color" : "#FF0000"`
normally I have to see two different color one for `not started` and other `completed`

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color on the series level

```
        var item = {
            name: task.name,
            data: [],
            color: task.intervals[0].color

        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/10/

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thanks million times :))